# Does defining a variable use more resources than overwriting a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript

If you plan to use a function that will overwrite the value of a variable many times, is it bad for performance to use `var` in the line that does the overwriting?

For example,

**Option 1**

```
var currentTile;
function setCurrentTile(index) {
    currentTile = $scope.tiles[index];
}
```

**Option 2**

```
function setCurrentTile(index) {
    var currentTile = $scope.tiles[index];
}
```

Historically, I've been using option #1 because it seemed intuitive to reduce the number of `var`'s in my code. But maybe it makes no difference and using the less verbose approach is more ideal.

Can anyone advise?

---

### **UPDATE FOR CONTEXT**

We generate a long array like below,

```
function prepGame() {
    // GENERATE TILE PATTERN
    var tiles = [];
    var times = 30;
    for ( var i = 0; i < times; i++ ) {
        tiles.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9));
    }
    $scope.tiles = tiles;
}
```

Then iterate through it, passing the values to `setCurrentTile(index)`. So `option 1` or `option 2` would be called 30 times.

Comment: What calls `setCurrentTile`? Hard to say without any context.

Comment: Updated with context.

Comment: `var` is used to declare a variable in the scope in which it's needed. If `currentTile` is not to be used outside of the function `setCurrentTile`, then declare it (use `var`) inside.

Comment: The resource cost of (maintaining) a binding itself is likely incredibly insignificant compared to everything else that is going on.

Comment: Say it with me:  "All performance problems worth dealing with are algorithmic in nature."  You're much better off eliminating wasted nested loops and repeated function calls than trying to chase down whether it's faster to use a global or a local variable.

Comment: Your example is over-simplified because neither option uses the variable after assignment, and the code in your update doesn't call the original code. Your option 1 does something that could affect other (not shown) parts of the program if they access that variable. Your option 2 doesn't do anything at all. The name of the function "setCurrentTile" implies that it would update state outside the function.

Comment: Also, just for context's sake, I don't think I'd call 30 items a "long array."  30,000 items maybe.  30 items is a small array.  My PC under chrome can push 30,000 items into an array in 12 milliseconds.  Don't worry about performance of tasks like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[The Love of] Premature optimization is the root of all evil.**

You should scope your variables based on the *correctness* of the program, not guesses about performance or memory utilization.  While it is academically true that local variables will be resolved more quickly than global ones, I would be frankly *shocked* to discover a real program in which there was enough difference between the two for a human user to notice.  There should little-to-no difference in memory usage between local and global variables.  (Normally, this would be no difference at all because a variable is a variable, but *instance* variables of objects could obviously be duplicated if there's more than one instance of the object)

A human user, however, *will* notice if the program produces incorrect results.  Generally speaking, [global variables are bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) because they make the program state harder to reason about.  That's not to say they're never appropriate, of course.  Use the scope that makes sense, and forget about performance until you can *prove* you have a real, *user-noticeable problem*.

Comment: Isn't it "The love of premature optimisation is the root of all evil"?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript we have function level scope and global scope. We can make variables local by wrapping code in a function. First of all variables are searched inside this local scope and if they are not found inside local scope then browser try to find them in the outer scope or if no other scope is present then in global scope... so obviously if a variable is found in local scope then time to access it will take less time then accessing it if it is present outside of function...

So in my opinion if you use variables inside a function then you will have 2 advantages...

1. Global namespace will not be polluted..
2. Time to access variables present inside current scope is always faster then accessing them if they are declared outside of current scope...

Answer (score 0):

In the **Option 1**

1. Javascript need search in the inner scope firstly searching the `setVarible`.
2. if this is not present, search in the outer scope. when Javascript matchs the variable,  set the given value.
3. Finally, the execution context of the `setCurrentTile` method it's done, the declared `var` variables are put in the garbage collector and then are destroyed.

If you notice, in terms of speed , was necessary search in the inner scope for a variable definition and also in the outter scope. In terms of system memory, the variable `keeping alive`. If this method it's called 30 times, this process will be executed and for each function call, will be necesary search in the inner and the outer scope impact in the speed of the application

In the **Option 2**

The variable `currentTitle` it's created in the execution context of the function, his value live only in this execution. This method saves in velocity terms , but will create and destroy 30 times the variable `currentTitle`. This means that the garbage collector will be called 30 times too.
I'm not Javascript expert and I dont know much about the garbage collector, but I think that the behaviour about **USE MORE RESOURCES** will depend of the engine where Javascript is running and how manage the garbage collector process.

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad covered the issue of scope very well, so I will follow up with a suggestion to test performance. JS has a method in the console namespace that allows for performance testing.  It's non-standard, so it should only be used in testing.  It might look something like:

```
var currentTile;
console.time("currentTile");
function setCurrentTile(index) {
    currentTile = $scope.tiles[index];
}
console.time("currentTile");
```

For further performance improvement, you can set loop length variables like this:

```
for(var i =0, times = 30; i < times; i++) {

}
```